# How can I insert this data correctly into my MySql table?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to make a form that inserts data into a table but it won't work correctly; everytime it echo's: "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1". Hopefully someone here can tell what I am doing wrong.

My SQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
 `serial` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `description` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `price` float NOT NULL,
 `picture` varchar(80) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`serial`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

My form:

```
<?php
include('config.php');

 echo '<h1 style="font-size:20px;">Sieraad toevoegen</h1>';
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (empty($_POST['naam']) || empty($_POST['prijs'])) {
        echo '<span style="color:red"><b>Niet alle velden zijn ingevuld!</b></span>';
    } else {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (name, description, picture, price) VALUES ('$_POST[naam]','$_POST[beschrijving]','$_POST[foto]', '$_POST[prijs]', NOW())") or die (mysql_error());
        echo '<span style="color:green"><b>Het sieraad is succesvol toegevoegd!</b></span>';
    }
}
echo '<form method="post" target="_self">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="serial">';
echo 'Naam van sieraad:<br><input type="text" name="naam"><br>';
echo 'Beschrijving:<br><textarea type="text" maxlength="250" name="beschrijving" rows="6" cols="37"></textarea><br>';
/**echo '<input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="102400" type="hidden">';**/
echo 'Foto:<br><input type="text" name="foto"><br>';
echo 'Prijs:<br><input type="text" name="prijs" maxlength:"7"><br>';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Toevoegen" onclick="this.value=\'Sieraad wordt verwerkt...\';"> <input type="reset" value="Wis velden">';
echo '</form>'; 
?>
```

**EDIT: Ok, didn't really think through the first post but now that I changed everything it still won't work..**

Comment: Define "but it won't work correctly"...

Comment: Can you explain how it's not working?

Answer (score 1):

Check your query

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (naam, beschrijving, prijs) VALUES
('$_POST[naam]','$_POST[beschrijving]','$_POST[prijs]', NOW())") or die (mysql_error());
```

you are passing 4 parameter for 3 variables.... they must be the same

Comment: what about the column names? Aren't they different from table schema?

Answer (score 1):

Set your form action to the current php file or you can leave it without the action attribute. (Do not set `action = ""` it violates HTML5 specs.)

Also in your SQL statement, `INSERT INTO products (naam, beschrijving, prijs) VALUES ('$_POST[naam]','$_POST[beschrijving]','$_POST[prijs]', NOW())`, you have 3 fields listed and 4 inputs. It is good to have the number of fields match the number inputs.

Finally, make sure your input statement field names match the table definition in your MySQL table. "name" does not equal "naam".

Answer (score 0):

Column names in insert query does not match with table schema. You should see the column error on die().